# XLR Adapters for Telinga EM23

Tags: binaural, field-recording

I've been hearing a lot of good stuff about Telinga-EM23 omni microphones for field recording, as it has low self noise specs.

I have plans to buy this mic & I use a SD MixPre-D hooked up with a Zoom H4n.

My questions are,

1. Since Telinga-EM23 comes with a 3.5mm output jack, i have to use a 3.5mm to a XLR adapter to hook it up to my mixpre-d right? so would using a 3.5mm to XLR adapter cause noise/hiss issues?
2. I have read & heard people use this mic for nature recordings or recording low level sources. So for example - does recording loud traffic sounds cause clipping with this mics?
3. Do you recommend using Telinga-EM23 only for recording low level sound sources & another set of mics for loud sources? or could Telinga-EM23 handle both?

My plan is basically to create a stealth binaural recording package, Kindly help me out here, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Pro 8 MK2 Handle has the xlr connector. Hopefully the connector is balanced and thus does not induce hiss. However hiss could be induced if the Output Noise of the Telinga mic is too high given its sensivity and the the noise floor of the Mix Pre D. You should take a look at the specs.
2. Loud traffic sounds are very problematic for low level source recording. Try take a picture of the stars in the middle of the day.
3. I don't think it is a matter of sound level. It is rather a matter of directivity. The dish makes you 'closer' of the source. The mic alone will be used for ambiance. If you need something in the middle range, you should consider a shotgun mic.